# WebAPI controller in deferent appdomain

Tags: asp.net-web-api, appdomain

Is it possible to isolate WebAPI controllers into their own appdomains so that if i have two dlls:

```
1.dll depends on services.dll version1  
/api/v1 <--has controller route

2.dll depends on services.dll version2  
/api/v2 <--has a controller route
```

dll1 and dll2 can be loaded into different appdomains.

I am unsure how to all the passthrough to their respective controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Create two different IIS Web Apps & app pools (one for each of these) and set up a 3rd IIS Site that has Application Request Routing and URL Rewrite turned on to delegate the necessary calls to each of these two web apps.  This will ensure that each uses a different worker process and thus will have their own appdomain.